# Preserving preprocessor definitions

Tags: c++, save, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I redefine a C++ macro then define it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-then-define-it-back)

Say I have some code that uses the name `BLAH` for a variable. Suppose `BLAH` is a common preprocessor definition in many standard header files (defined as 10), so if my file is included after any of them, the code breaks because `BLAH` is transformed into 10; therefore, I must `#undef BLAH`. But also other headers may depend on `BLAH`, so I must restore `BLAH` to it's original value after my header is done. Is it possible to do something like this:

```
#ifdef BLAH
#define BLAH_OLD BLAH
#undef BLAH
#endif

... code ...

// restore BLAH to 10
#ifdef BLAH_OLD
#define BLAH BLAH_OLD
#end
```

? This doesn't work of course, because BLAH is not expanded to 10. I have tried doing something like

```
#define EXPAND_AGAIN(x) x
#define EXPAND(x) EXPAND_AGAIN(x)
#define BLAH_OLD EXPAND(BLAH)
```

but that doesn't work either, since EXPAND is taken literally and not expanded. I am using MSVC 2008/2010, but it would be lovely if the solution would work on most other compilers too.

Comment: Have you considered changing your variable naming?

Comment: Change the name of your variable; terrible convention you've got going on there if this is a problem. And how about instead of "let's say" you say "here's the actual problem I'm trying to solve."

Comment: You do realize the it has been a convention from nearly the beginning of time that identifiers that are all caps are reserved for use by the pre-processor (to avoid things like this).

Answer (score 38):

Yes, given that your compiler supports the push/pop macro directives (visual c++, gcc, llvm all do):

```
#define BLAH 10

#pragma push_macro("BLAH")
#undef BLAH

#define BLAH 5

...

#pragma pop_macro("BLAH")
```

Comment: This seems to be Microsoft compiler specific.

Comment: Sorry, standard C++ does not define `push_macro` (Visual C++ has this #pragma, but it's not standard C++). Cheers,

Comment: At least some versions of GCC also support it.

Comment: I've just edited my comment to address that, latest gcc/llvm support it as well, not sure when was it added to gcc though.

Comment: clang can handle this, too.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the preprocessor doesn't support a stack of definitions.

The Boost preprocessor library makes the preprocessor do things you'd never imagine it could do (like effectively variadic macros in C++98), but is bound by the inherent limitations of the preprocessor -- so, no can do, sorry.

The only known half-way remedy is to reserve `ALL_UPPERCASE_IDENTIFIERS` for macros, and consistently always use them for macros. It reduces the name collision problem somewhat. Unfortunately the C standard library defines a number of lowercase macros, or allows for their existence, like e.g. `assert`, but they are just a few.

From a practical point of view the main problem is in Windows programming, where Microsoft's [windows.h] header defines *zillions* of non-uppercase macros, including, by default, `min` and `max` which conflict with the C++ standard library.

So, for Windows C++ programming, always define `NOMINMAX` before including [windows.h].

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: thanks for `NOMINMAX`, but there is `#pragma push_macro` at least

Comment: @Sergei: Yes, `#pragma push_macro` is [the accepted solution in the duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1794089/464581). But as I noted in a comment on another answer for this question, it was non-standard in 2010. I believe it's still non-standard, although it's supported by, at least, Visual C++, g++ and clang.

Answer (score 0):

I used to believe that the very same trick you tried does work, as I used to use it myself.  But I eventually learned that it actually does not work at all.  The simple answer is NO, you cannot save a define's current value, change it, and then restore the old value.  The preprocessor simply does not work that way.  Once you define a new value, the old value is gone.

Answer (score -3):

One trick that works for me is to use an enum in the class.

```
class foo
{
public:
  enum { blah = 10 } myenum;
}
```

Then you can just use

```
foo:blah
```

when you need '10'.

Since it's part of the class then other uses of 'blah' won't conflict and you save all that def'ing and undef'ing.

Comment: What? `#define blah 0`, breaks your code.

Comment: -1 for Advice That Generally Does Not Work. If "blah" is already defined as a preprocessor macro, the enum definition will most probably be syntactically ill-formed. The only possibility of passing is when "blah" is defined as a valid identifier. Cheers,

Comment: replace the macro with the enum and all the issues of dealing with macro collisions go away. It won't fix 'pushing' a value.

Comment: I don't think this will help with, for example, STL `max`. Its a function nearly everywhere except Windows, which defines it as a macro (even in VS2015/C++11). See [PRB: Using STL in Windows Program Can Cause Min/Max Conflicts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/143208).