# How to copy macro contents to another macro in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I redefine a c++ macro for a few includes and then define it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-for-a-few-includes-and-then-define-it-back)

I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>    

#define A 1  // define a macro
#define B A  // copy macro? (note this does not work...)
#undef A     // undefine first macro
#define A 2  // redefine it as something else

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
  std::cout << A << " " << B;
  return 0;
}
```

My program prints "2 2".  I want it to print "2 1".  How do I do this?  (BTW, please forgive the mixing of C++ in a **C** question.  I really just care about the preprocessor portion of the question, which I would like to be C99 compliant.)

Eventually I would like to do something like:

```
// In file A
#define A 1  // define a macro

// In file B
#include "fileA.h"

#define B A  // copy macro?
#undef A     // undefine first macro
#define A 2  // redefine it as something else

// #include other files using A

#define A B  // set macro back to original value, whatever that was.
```

UPDATE - Already answered here:

[Can I redefine a C++ macro then define it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-for-a-few-includes-and-then-define-it-back)