# Can I disable a macro in an inner function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I redefine a C++ macro then define it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-then-define-it-back)

I have an application that calls a function from a third party SDK lots of times along the app lifetime. This third party function checks for some errors with its _3RDPARTY_ASSERT (which is a wrapper around _ASSERT).

My problem is that in one of these calls, I sometimes expect an error (and handle it afterwards). I would like to disable the assert in this case, as it's quite annoying while debugging, but keep it in all the other cases.

I have tried to handle it with pragma push_macro/pop_macro but I haven't found a way.
Is this possible?

I have the source of 3rdParty.cpp but would prefer not to touch it.

This would be a simplified version of the code:

**mine.cpp:**

```
#include "3rdparty.h"

HRESULT MyMethod(...)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = _3rdParty(...);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = _3rdParty(...);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = _3rdParty(...);
    ...    
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        hr = _3rdParty(...); // This call shouldn't throw the assertion, as I expect it to fail sometimes!
    if (FAILED(hr))
        doSomething();
    else
        doSomethingElse();
    ...
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
       hr = _3rdParty(...);
    return hr;    
}
```

**3rdParty.cpp:**

```
...
#define _3RDPARTY_ASSERT (_ASSERT)
...
HRESULT _3rdParty(...)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = SomeFunction();
    _3RDPARTY_ASSERT(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    return hr;
}
```

Comment: @Jon: It's not a duplicate. That question is about the general case, with a relatively simple solution, and this is about a specific case with no obvious solution.

Comment: You are correct, sorry for that.

Comment: Closed? Doesn't people know how to read anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that unless it is inlined, the function will be tokenized and compiled a single time. This means it doesn't matter if the macro is defined or not when you call the function, only when it is compiling the function itself.

Comment: I know that... I was hoping there was some kind of workaround :)

Comment: Since you want to change how the function is defined, but only at one specific call, I don't really see how. Sorry.

Is there no other way you can handle this first and then save the error info for processing later?

Comment: I don't think so. I could add a _3rdParty_NoAssert() with the exact same code but without the assert. I'm trying to avoid that, though.

Comment: Them I'm afraid I don't see a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the definition of `_3RDPARTY_ASSER`, like

```
#define _3RDPARTY_ASSERT definition
```

Then you save that definition:

```
#define SAVE_ASSERT definition
```

Then in the place in your code when you don't want an assertion you could `#undef _3RDPARTY_ASSERT` or `#define` it to something else.

After that code you can re-enable the old definition by

```
#define _3RDPARTY_ASSERT SAVE_ASSERT
```

A second solution, which I prefer, is this: If you have access to the 3'd party code, you can create another version of `_3rdParty(...)` which doesn't assert, then use it as needed.

Comment: Except he wants to disable it within a call, not where the macro is specified itself, so redefining the macro at that point won't make a difference. Your second solution, however, seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks! As Agentlien stated, the first part is not useful for my specific problem. I fear I will have to create another version of the method...