# Define a macro then undefine it if it was previously undefined

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I'm including header files which require certain pro-processor `#define`s to be present, however I do not want this to pollute the rest of my code e.g.:

```
// FOO may or may not already be defined here
#define FOO
#include "Bar.h"
#undef FOO
// FOO should be defined or not, as per the starting state
```

I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
#ifdef FOO
#define FOO_DEFINED
#endif

#define FOO
#include "Bar.h"

#ifndef FOO_DEFINED
#undef FOO
#else
#undef FOO_DEFINED
#endif
```

Questions:

1. Will the above work i.e. restore all macro definitions (or lack of) to the state they were in beforehand?
2. Is there perhaps a simpler solution?
3. Does it matter if FOO was already defined when I `#define` it? Should I add another `#ifndef` to protect against this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I redefine a C++ macro then define it back?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-then-define-it-back)

Comment: @Roddy do the solutions on that question work if the macro is initially undefined?

Comment: @MarkRansom : Well, the accepted one does, for gcc (and probably msvc) anyway: If you push and pop an undefined macro, the macro ends back to being undefined. http://ideone.com/s2iVk8 fails to compile, as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that in your example, Bar.h cares only whether FOO is defined or not, and not the actual expression bound to it.  Furthermore, if someone else (I presume your code example is, itself, in a header file) defines FOO and cares about the expression bound to it, you don't want to make the mistake of redefining FOO with an empty expression.  If so, you might want to simplify:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
#define UNDEF_FOO
#endif

#include "Bar.h"

#ifdef UNDEF_FOO
#undef FOO
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much neater than mine, and solves an additional problem as you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

1. yes it should work.
2. I have #pragma push_macro/pop_macro("macro_name") in mind, but it might work only in gcc and MS VC++
3. yes, it matters, you'll get a warning if it is defined again with a different value. As you state, you can shield it with #ifndef.