# How to rename a C preprocessor macro?

Tags: c, macros

Consider a (read-only third-party) header `lib.h` with:

```
#define XYZ 42
```

In a source file, I want to use the word `XYZ` for an unrelated purpose, and do not want the substitution with `42`. But, in the same source file, for other purposes, I also do want to access the value `42` from `lib.h` without hardcoding it. How do I *rename* the macro from `XYZ` to, say, `LIB_XYZ`?

The following does not work, because preprocessor wants `XYZ` at the time the `LIB_XYZ` substitution is made, but `XYZ` had been undefined:

```
#include "lib.h"
#define LIB_XYZ XYZ
#undef XYZ
```

Is there a way to trick the preprocessor into expanding `LIB_XYZ` to its final value before `XYZ` is lost?

Comment: I think you are stuck, if you want to get the definition of LIB_XYZ from the third party header file, and don't want to use anything but the C compiler. If I had to do this, I'd probably write a script to transform lib.h into our_lib.h, with selected #define's modified, make my code include our_lib.h, and use a makefile to make the right thing happen if lib.h changed.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-then-define-it-back) can help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not with the pre-processor, at least, not that I am aware of.

However, for simple constants with known type like in your example, there is a workaround.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// <xyz.h>

#define XYZ 42

// </xyz.h>

enum xyz_constants
{
  LIB_XYZ = XYZ,
};

#undef XYZ

#define XYZ 27

int
main()
{
  printf("old value: %d, new value: %d\n", LIB_XYZ, XYZ);
  return 0;
}
```

Not showing the fluff from `stdio.h`, this code is pre-processed to the following.

```
enum xyz_constants
{
  LIB_XYZ = 42,
};

int
main()
{
  printf("old value: %d, new value: %d\n", LIB_XYZ, 27);
  return 0;
}
```

You can extend this to some degree to other data types and certain function-like macros but there are of course limits.

Anyway, why do you need the particular identifier `XYZ`? Can't you use a different name for your macro?

Comment: The enum trick was brilliant! Thank you! Re why: XYZ is a substring of another third-party macro that I'm constructing via concatenation, and the concatenation macro is generic (works for XYZ or ABC or whatever), so stuck with XYZ.

Comment: This solution just saved me :)

Comment: In the general case, a solution involving `#undef XYZ` may not work. The library may refer to `XYZ` in the replacement texts of its macros; those macros will break of `XYZ` is undefined or redefined to something else. If you know what those macros are and can avoid them, then it's workable.

Answer (score 4):

If `XYZ` from `lib.h` is a *number* [or a constant of a variety], you could use an `enum`:

```
enum { LIB_XYZ = XYZ };
#undef XYZ
```

If `XYZ` is *not* the above, you have to create (e.g.) `myxyz.c` that does *not* include `lib.h` and use `XYZ` there (other files may include `xyz.h`)

The difference is that `#define LIB_XYZ XYZ` will *not* be resolved at that line, only when you use it later, as in:

```
foo(LIB_XYZ);
```

so that won't work because you've already `#undef'ed` the `XYZ`.

Answer (score 0):

Use another .c file, and assign the macro value to a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

A preprocessor symbol **is a** name.  There is no preprocessing directive which changes the name itself, while preserving the contents. For instance, given either:

```
#define FOO 42
```

or

```
#define FOO(x, y)  x ## y (
```

There is no way to define a macro called `BAR` which has the same contents, without repeating these definitions. That is to say, there is no operation like:

```
#alias BAR FOO  // nonexistent fantasy macro-cloning preprocessor directive
```

Nor like this:

```
#rename BAR FOO // like #alias BAR FOO followed by #undef FOO
```

If we do this:

```
#define BAR FOO  // for the #define FOO 42 case
```

it's not an alias. Macro `BAR` is defined such that its replacement token sequence is the token `FOO`, and not `42`.   If the `FOO` macro disappears, then `BAR` loses its meaning.

Note also that C preprocessor macros cannot expand into preprocessing directives, so the following approach also **will not work**:

```
 // wrong:
 #define MACRO_DEFINER(NAME) \
   #define NAME 42

 MACRO_DEFINER(FOO) // hoping for #define FOO 42: no such luck
 MACRO_DEFINER(BAR) // hoping for #define BAR 42: likewise
```

I'm afraid that you have to take a few steps back to find an alternative strategy to whatever problem you're trying to solve. If you get stuck, create a new question about the actual problem.

There is always code generation: generating C or C++ at build time. Then any textual substitution or expansion you can dream of is possible, if you just tweak your generation system.

Any solution that involves `#undef XYZ` risks brekaing the functionality of the library header. The library might do something like this:

#define XYZ 42
   #define macro(B) bloop(XYZ, B)

If we are using `macro`, then we break it if we redefine `XYZ`.

If the library is known for defining `XYZ` and we manage to redefine it successfully in code which uses that library, the situation will be confusing to future maintainers. "Oh, this `XYZ` is not actually that library one; this programmer just wanted an unrelated `XYZ`."

The best solution here is to stop wanting to use `XYZ` and find some other name. Adapt to the libraries you're using; don't clash with them.