# Preprocessor definition duplication

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I have two libraries and unfortunately they define two identical preprocessor definitions (which I need to use):

lib1.h

```
#define MYINT 1
```

lib2.h

```
#define MYINT 2
```

In my program I need to use both of them:

```
#include <Lib1.h>
#include <lib2.h>
...
int myint = MYINT;
```

And here I have error that MYINT can't be resolved.

How can I solve that when I cannot modify the lib files?

Comment: You've not stated what you want `MYINT` to ultimately be at this stage, you can `#ifdef MYINT #undef MYINT` etc..

Comment: The preprocessor is going to replace the macro with the value, which one does it have to choose?

Comment: Which version of the macro do you need?

Comment: Do you have the luxury of targetting only one operating system? If so, which one? I'm thinking in terms of linking the libraries dynamically.

Comment: @Bathsheba: How would dynamic linking resolve collisions in preprocessor identifiers?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The intention would be to abstract all naming conflicts away from the consuming library. Of course we can't say too much more without further details, which are lacking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might `#undef MYINT` before to include the header as workaround.

```
#undef MYINT
#include <Lib1.h>
const int myint_lib1 = MYINT; // 1

#undef MYINT
#include <lib2.h>
const int myint_lib2 = MYINT; // 2
```

Comment: Use `constexpr` if possible.

Comment: BTW, first `#undef` isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

Get the `MYINT` value of the first library before the second one replaces it.

```
#include <Lib1.h>
int myInt1 = MYINT;
#undef MYINT
#include <lib2.h>
int myInt2 = MYINT;
#undef MYINT
```

Of course, that doesn't work if `MYINT` is something dynamic and you need to keep its actual content around.

Edited by handy999: no semicolon at the end of preprocessor statements.

Comment: I would add #undef MYINT after each to avoid warnings and misuse

Comment: Good suggestion, I added it to the answer.

Comment: The two libs already were identified to have a naming conflict. Including them into one translation unit seems very optimistic to me.

Comment: You're right. The root problem is that two libs are using macro names that aren't specific enough not to create a naming conflict like this. Ideally I'd try to tackle the "cannot modify the lib" part.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I would take is to derive from each of the include files an extended version of the include files which will provide the `MYINT` through a different mechanism outside of the include files themselves.

So create an include file from `lib1.h` named `lib1_ext.h` containing the following lines:

```
#if !defined(MYLIB1_EXT_H_INCLUDED)
#define MYLIB1_EXT_H_INCLUDED
// ensure that MYINT is not defined no matter what order the include files are used
#undef MYINT
#include "lib1.h"
const int myInt_lib1 = MYINT;  // make a copy of the value of MYINT if it is needed
// make sure MYINT is undefined to allow the compiler to catch any dependencies on it
#undef MYINT
#endif
```

and similarly for `lib2.h` create `lib2_ext.h` as in:

```
#if !defined(MYLIB2_EXT_H_INCLUDED)
#define MYLIB2_EXT_H_INCLUDED
// ensure that MYINT is not defined no matter what order the include files are used
#undef MYINT
#include "lib2.h"
const int myInt_lib2 = MYINT;  // make a copy of the value of MYINT if it is needed
// make sure MYINT is undefined to allow the compiler to catch any dependencies on it
#undef MYINT
#endif
```

now when using any of the functionality of the library use the respective copy of the `MYINT` value, `myInt_lib1` when using `lib1.h` functionality and/or `myInt_lib2` when using `lib2.h` functionality. However if `MYINT` is only used with the library header file itself and is not needed anywhere to actually use the library then you can just discard that statement.

See as well [Can I redefine a C++ macro then define it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/can-i-redefine-a-c-macro-then-define-it-back) which shows how to save and restore a macro definition with some vendors' compilers and the `pragma` directive. It doesn't look like that is really applicable with your posting however.

That posting also has an answer which describes the basics of macro expansion and why the `const int myInt_lib1 = MYINT;` is needed to save the value of `MYINT` rather than using the Preprocessor as in `#define MYINT_LIB1  MYINT` to save the value of `MYINT`. The Preprocessor delays the expansion of a macro as long as possible and the result is that trying to use a Preprocessor macro as in `#define MYINT_LIB1  MYINT` to save the value of `MYINT` doesn't work once `MYINT` is undefined using the `#undef` directive. When the Preprocessor first replaces the text `MYINT_LIB1` with the text `MYINT` and then does a rescan, since `MYINT` is now undefined, the text `MYINT` remains and the result is a compiler error if you are lucky.

**One thing to consider with this work around**

This work around assumes that all that is needed is the numerical value of `MYINT` which is treated as an `int` constant value. So it assumes that the places where `MYINT` is used are places where a `const int` can also be used.

This means that any kind of token pasting, `#if` test or other Preprocessor action that involves treating the text which `MYINT` is defined as text that can be used by the Preprocessor for other macro operations is not going to work properly outside of the places where the `lib.h` or `lib2.h` are included and processed by the Preprocessor.

It also means that you can not specify a compiler option to declare `MYINT` as a part of conditional compilation since the macro created by the compiler option is going to be ignored and eliminated by this work around.

So any dependency that the source generated by the Preprocessor has on `MYINT` as a text macro outside of each of the include files will cause the compile to break.

An example of a possible dependency would be a macro within `lib1.h` which uses `MYINT` to create an additional, unseen argument to a function as in:

```
int funcStuff (int a, struct b *pBthing);

#define FUNCSTUFF (pBthing)  funcStuff(MYINT, (pBthing))
```

with the expectation that anybody using the library would use `FUNCSTUFF(&bThing);` rather than `funcStuff (MYINT, &bThing);`. To make this work you would need to either use the function `funcStuff()` directly as in `funcStuff(myInt_lib1, &bThing);` or make your own version of the `FUNCSTUFF()` macro that uses `myInt_lib1` rather than `MYINT`.

Answer (score 0):

With no preprocessor tricks:

**lib1_handler.h**

```
extern int lib1_handler_myint;
// or
int lib1_handler_myint_f();
```

**lib1_handler.c**

```
#include <Lib1.h>

int lib1_handler_myint = MYINT;
// or
int lib1_handler_myint_f() { return MYINT; }
```

**lib2_handler.h**

```
extern int lib2_handler_myint;
// or
int lib1_handler_myint_f();
```

**lib2_handler.c**

```
#include <Lib2.h>

int lib2_handler_myint = MYINT;
// or
int lib2_handler_myint_f() { return MYINT; }
```

**main.c**

```
#include "lib1_handler.h"
#include "lib2_handler.h"

int void () {
  return lib1_handler_myint || lib2_handler_myint_f();
}
```