# How to use enum identifier when a macro of same name exists?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, macros

I am trying to work with an enum where one of the enum values is defined as a macro.

```
enum class Method
{
  GET, 
  POST, 
  PUT, 
  HEAD 
  // I want to add DELETE
};
```

This enum is being used ahead where values are being converted to string.

But when I add `DELETE` it says this is defined as a macro in one of the `.h` files I am using in the class - `winnt.h`.

In `winnt.h`, `DELETE` is defined as:

```
#define DELETE                           (0x00010000L)
```

The compiler gives an error saying 'expected an identifier'.

I don't want to change my code WHERE the enum is being used and converted to a string.

How can I add this `DELETE` value to my enum?

Comment: please post a [mcve] of the code that has the error and include the error message in the question

Comment: what is `DELETE` defined as ?

Comment: what do you expect to get from using `(0x00010000L)` as the name for an enumerator?

Comment: I know that DELETE is getting replaced by (0x00010000L) when I try using it as enum value. As the macro definition is something I cannot handle, is there a way to bypass the definition when using it in enum

Comment: @churill yes, more context has been added in the meantime, though it was my misunderstanding from the start ;)

Comment: This problem goes away if we stop shouting. You use a scoped C++ enum already, `get`, `post` and such would work beautifully since you need to qualify them anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica coincidentally, no. `delete` is a keyword ;)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - Wise cracking does not detract from the more general point of macro clashing

Comment: @StoryTeller its not OPs macro, so changing their spelling wont make the issue go away. Though, I get your point, the issue is the macro (be it OPs or not)

Comment: Useful rule of thumb since time immemorial: if it's not a macro, don't make it look like a macro.

Comment: First write your code as a static library (with all C++ code in namespaces), make sure this library is independent from windows header files. (If you need OS calls, then make those calls through an abstract baseclass/interface).  Then make a seperate project to build and link your exe or dll (and OS specific implementation of your abstract baseclass). Added bonus you're one step closer to unit testability (and portability)

Comment: Uppercase is generally used for macros. You'd better not use it otherwise. But, since the lower case `delete` is a keyword, you're gonna need another name; `del` is an abbreviation fitting the less-than-4-character criterion that other values already satisfy.

Comment: Or, you can simply use `Delete` instead, since macros and keywords are case-sensitive. Or, incorporate the fact that these are HTTP methods, like `HttpDelete`, etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DELETE` is a pre-existing [Standard Access Right](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/standard-access-rights) flag used with
various Win32 APIs, such as `CreateFile()`.

Your only options to use your own `DELETE` value are to either:

- Don't use `winnt.h` in the same translation unit as your `enum`.
- `#undef` the existing `DELETE` macro before declaring your `enum`. See [Can I redefine a C++ macro then define it back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793800/) and other similar questions for how to preserve the old macro value so you can restore it afterwards (note: not all compilers support doing this).

Otherwise, you will have to rename your `enum` value to something else that is not already in use.

Comment: `undef`fing potentially leads to issues and may result in order of includes changing meaning of code. I'd favor one of the other options

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number depending on which compiler is used, there may be ways to work around the `#undef` issue. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number "potentially leads to issues" Not in practice.